# (Python) How to group unique values in column with total of another column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-science, pandas-groupby

This is a sample what my dataframe looks like:

```
company_name country_code state_code software finance commerce etc......
google       USA           CA          1        0          0
jimmy        GBR           unknown     0        0          1
```

I would like to be able to group the industry of a company with its state code. For example I would like to have the total number of software companies in a state etc. (e.g. 200 software companies in CA, 100 finance companies in NY).

I am currently just counting the number of total companies in each state using:

```
 usa_df['state_code'].value_counts()
```

But I can't figure out how to group the number of each type of industry in each individual state.

Comment: For example you want to find How many Google in CA?

Comment: Hi @PiyushS.Wanare, thanks for the reply. No I would like to find the total number of software companies in every states, the total number of finance companies in every state etc. ( For example: Software, CA, 1200) <- This would state that there are 1200 software companies in CA.

Comment: df.iloc[:, 2:].groupby(“state_code”).sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 1s and 0s are boolean flags for each category then you should just need sum.

```
df[df.country_code == 'USA'].groupby('state_code').sum().reset_index()

#  state_code  commerce  finance  software
#0         CA         0        0         1
```

Comment: If you want to keep the `'unknowns'` then remove the `df.country_code == 'USA'`, but this will ensure you only collect states in the USA

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['state_code']).agg({'software' : 'sum', 'finance' : 'sum', ...})
```

This will group by the state_code, and sum up the number of 'software', 'finance', etc in each grouping.

Could also do a pivot_table:

```
df.pivot_table(index = 'state_code', columns = ['software', 'finance', ...], aggfunc = 'sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
result_dataframe = dataframe_name.groupby('state_code ').sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!